# How do i use if else statement using xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print the output on console where i do have labels(headings), question(labels) and as its answer i am printing the random string as answer. When its just a label it does not have the `<input>` tag. And the question(label) contain the `<input>`. My code is printing Label Name, then Random string and then question(label). It should be Label Name(Patient Detail), Question(Last name) and Random String.

HTML Code for Label(Member Name is a label)

```
<div _ngcontent-tir-c77="" class="TextBox">
    <h1 _ngcontent-tir-c77="" id="11111"></h1><!----><!----><!---->
    <app-input _ngcontent-tir-c77="" inputtype="text" _nghost-tir-c24="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-star-inserted"><
      div _ngcontent-tir-c24=""><!----><!---->
        <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="input ng-star-inserted">
           <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="col-sm-12 col-md">
              <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="form-group"><!---->
                 <label _ngcontent-tir-c24="" aria-hidden="true" class="ql-editor ng-star-inserted" for="a.MemberName" xpath="1" style="">a. Member Name</label>
              <div _ngcontent-tir-c24=""><!----><!----><!----><!---->
              <mat-menu _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="">
```

HTML code for Question (Last div tag contains the `<input>` )

```
 <div _ngcontent-tir-c77="" class="TextBox">
        <h1 _ngcontent-tir-c77="" id="11111"></h1><!----><!----><!---->
        <app-input _ngcontent-tir-c77="" inputtype="text" _nghost-tir-c24="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-star-inserted"><
          div _ngcontent-tir-c24=""><!----><!---->
            <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="input ng-star-inserted">
               <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="col-sm-12 col-md">
                  <div _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="form-group"><!---->
                     <label _ngcontent-tir-c24="" aria-hidden="true" class="ql-editor ng-star-inserted" for="Last" xpath="1" style="">**Last** </label><!----><!----><!----><!---->
                       **<input** _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" type="text" id="Last" placeholder="" -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                  <mat-menu _ngcontent-tir-c24="" class="">
```

I tried following code:

try {

```
if(answerType.equals("TextBox"))
{ 

    WebElement tlabel = answers.get(ans) .findElement(By.tagName("label"));
    System.out.println(tlabel.getText());                   

  if(answers.get(ans).findElement(By.xpath("//app-input[@inputtype='text']/div/div/div/div[@class='form-group']/div/input")).getTagName().equals("input"))
    //  if(answers.get(ans).findElement(By.xpath("//app-input[@inputtype='text']/div/div/div/div[@class='form-group']/div/input"))!= null) //Same output                
    // if(answers.get(ans).findElement(By.tagName("input")) != null)   -Not worked
{              
WebElement textbox = answers.get(ans).findElement(By.xpath("//app-input[@inputtype='text']/div/div/div/div[@class='form-group']/div/input"));
textbox.sendKeys(getSaltString());
System.out.println(textbox.getAttribute("value"));
                        }  
                    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Use find_elements to find all the child elements. if the length >0 check the tag name and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @Sureshmani, i tried as you suggested but did not work for me. Thanks.